# Can't install anything but cuda 10.1 with driver version 430

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I've been trying to roll back to cuda 10.0 with no success. I previously had Cuda 10.1 on my system, which had been installed using a runfile. I uninstalled it using the uninstall script. However, now whenever I try to install a different version of CUDA, I get `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`.

I have tried completely removing all versions of cuda and nvidia drivers using

sudo apt --purge remove nvidia-*
sudo apt --purge remove cuda*

Then I reinstalled just the driver to see if I could get nvidia-smi to work. However, if I install 410 or 418, I get the same error message. nvidia-smi only works if I install 430.

All I can think is that there are some files that were put in place by the runfile that never got removed and that's corrupting my installation. I have been using .deb files to install cuda 10.0 and the ubuntu repository for the drivers.

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and I have two rtx 2080ti. I have been rebooting after installing drivers, removing drivers, and installing CUDA.

Comment: Yes I did reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try purging libnvidia-compute-390 (both 64bit and 32 bit).  That's the packge with libcuda.so.*

---

You might have up to 14 packages starting with libnvidia- associated with a specific Nvidia driver.  None of these would have been picked up with a purge of "nvndia-*"

Comment: Tried that before. Only the runfile option mentioned in my response has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the 430 driver and then install cuda 10.0 using a runfile (and putting no when asked if I want to install drivers). It's running now.